# Can you plot the expressions in a list without Evaluate[]?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

Plot is forcing me to choose between two bad options.

I have a function `g` that is a numerical integral which I want to plot for multiple values of a parameter.

```
    f[x_, a_] = E^(Sin[a*x]);
    g[x_, a_] := NIntegrate[f[xprime, a], {xprime, 0, x}];
    parameterList = {1, 2};
    Plot[Evaluate[Table[g[x, a], {a, parameterList}]], {x, 0, 3 Pi}, 
      PlotLabels -> Table[Row[{"a = ", a}], {a, parameterList}]]
```

This code outputs the plot that I want I want, but it also gives me "xprime = x is not a valid limit of integration" errors. Because of Evaluate[], the hold on Table[] is broken, so NIntegrate thinks I'm trying to run it with a symbolic x instead of numerical.

If I don't include the Evaluate[], then the function is computed properly for all values of x, but now "Plot does not see a list of
expressions. Instead it sees a list of numeric values which is
treated as a single function with multiple values and
consequently plotted in a single color." I found that explanation in [this discussion from 11 years ago](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/c/xSp_AzI30SU/m/jSh9Oa0zis4J) about whether Plot should work this way. The commenters make it sound as though the only way for Plot to distinguish two curves is if they're explicit expressions of x, but sometimes you can't write things as explicit expressions of x, like in the case of NIntegrate where it needs to be left unevaluated until you input a numerical value.

Is there an elegant way to produce this plot without errors? Is there an alternative to evaluate that says "here is an explicit expression of x, but it is still held until the moment you assign x a value"? Or is this just a fundamental limit from Plot's implementation decisions?

Thanks

Comment: It would really be better to not pass in the variable/symbol to be used in the integration as an argument to g and f. But fixing that is a bit of an adventure. Maybe the simplest thing to do would be to map Plot over your parameterList and wrap the whole thing in Show.

Comment: You could also just wrap the whole thing in Quiet.

Comment: Since `g` is defined using a numeric technique, its arguments should be restricted to being numeric, i.e., `g[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := ...` Then `Evaluate` would not cause a problem.

Comment: @lericr Do you mean something like this? `Show[Plot[g[x, #], {x, 0, 3 Pi}] & /@ parameterList]` In order to change colour for each curve, you would have to do something more complicated in order to change the colour within each Plot call, but I do think that would work. Quiet is also a good idea.

@Bob Hanlon This is a really good solution. I guess I should always be using this pattern testing in numerical functions. Thanks.